# How to find the name of php script that posted the data to another php script?

Tags: php

How one can find the name php script that posted data to current php script.
I am having two scripts X.php and Y.php respectively. These scripts can post data to a php script process.php. In process.php how can I find that which script (from X.php or Y.php) have posted data to process.php

Comment: Is this all happening server side or is it posting actual form data via a browser (`http://<site>/X.php` form POST to `http://<site>/process.php`)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$previous = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not very reliable. Some browsers will return a null result all the time, some will carry the original URL across 3xx responses, some are just plain broken.

Answer (score 1):

If your *X.php* and *Y.php* post data via a HTML form, then a quick and easy way is to give different names to the submit button:

**X.php:**

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="X" value="submit">
</form>
```

**Y.php:**

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="Y" value="submit">
</form>
```

**process.php**

```php
<?php
if (isset($_POST['X'])) {
    // the request came from X.php
}
if (isset($_POST['Y'])) {
    // the request came from Y.php
}
?>
```

If you call *process.php* via AJAX then add a key to your request data like described above, for instance (with jQuery) in *X.php*:

```
$.post({
    url: 'process.php',
    data: { ......., X: 1}
});
```